# Elementwise multiplication of tensors of unknown dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

How do I do an elementwise multiplication of tensors with the following shapes? The second array here is always assumed to be 2D.

```
[x, y, ?, ?, ?, ...] * [x, y]
```

I want to broadcast over all the dimensions marked ?, of which I don't know the number a-priori. Possible solutions I have considered (but don't know how to do):

- Add a variable number of axes to the second array
- Reverse the order of the axes of both arrays and then reverse them back again

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Yes, the second array is always 2D in this case. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the input arrays are `A`, `B` with `B` as the `2D` array. To start off, reshape `A` to a `3D` array with the trailing non-matching dimensions merged as one dimension, then perform the broadcasted elementwise multiplication with `B` and finally reshape back the product to original shape of `A`. The implementation would look like this -

```
shp = A.shape  # Get shape of A
out = (A.reshape(shp[0],shp[1],-1)*B[:,:,None]).reshape(shp)
```

Verify output -

```
In [96]: A = np.random.rand(2,3,4,5,7,8,4)

In [97]: B = np.random.rand(2,3)

In [98]: shp = A.shape
    ...: out = (A.reshape(shp[0],shp[1],-1)*B[:,:,None]).reshape(shp)
    ...: 

In [99]: direct_out = A*B[:,:,None,None,None,None,None]

In [100]: np.allclose(out,direct_out) # Verify
Out[100]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

The alternatives mentioned in the question (with `b` the 2D array):

- Add a variable number of axes to the second array

  ```
  a * b.reshape(b.shape + (1,)*(a.ndim-b.ndim))
  ```
- Reverse the order of the axes of both arrays and then reverse them back again

  ```
  (a.T * b.T).T
  ```

Another alternative with einsum:

```
numpy.einsum('ij...,ij->ij...', a, b)
```

Comment: That `einsum` approach is elegant!

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 4, 5, 6))
b = np.zeros((3, 4))
c = a*b[(slice(None), slice(None), )+(None, )*(a.ndim-2)]
```